# Passing Value to Modal

Tags: php

I have this table of data where I am going to get the id of each row and pass it to the modal and the modal will show the further details of the id. For now, when each row is clicked, the modal will pop up and show more of the details. I am also going to do the same with the edit, only have the values in an input type.

Here is the code for the table:

```
 <?php
echo ''.$row[0].'';
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root");  
    mysql_select_db("thesis");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM childinfo Order by lastName ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
      {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
          if ($childID==$row[0]){

          echo '<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white text-center rounded"><h6>Childs Basic Information</label></h6></div><br>';
          echo '<b>Full Name: </b>'.$row[1].', ' .$row[2]. ' '.$row[3].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Gender: </b>'.$row[11].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Birthday: </b>'.$row[5].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Age: </b>'.$row[6].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Name of Main Household: </b>'.$childID.'<br><br>';
          echo '<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white text-center rounded"><h6>Childs Health Information</label></h6></div><br>';
          echo '<b>Height: </b> <input type="text" name="height" class="form-control" value="'.$row[8].'">';
          echo '<b>Weight: </b><input type="text" name="weight" class="form-control" value="'.$row[7].'">';
          echo '<b>BMI: </b><input type="text" name="bmi" class="form-control" value="'.$row[9].'">';
           echo '<b>Date Weighed: </b><input type="date" name="dateWeighed" class="form-control" value="'.$row[13].'">';
          echo '<b>Health History: </b><input type="text" name="healthHis" class="form-control" value="'.$row[12].'">';


      }}}
?>
```

Here is the code for my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="view" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Child Profile</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">


<?php
echo ''.$childID.'';
    $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root");  
    mysql_select_db("thesis");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM childinfo Order by lastName ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
      {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){

          if ($childID==$row[0]){
          echo '<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white text-center rounded"><h6>Childs Basic Information</label></h6></div><br>';
          echo '<b>Full Name: </b>'.$row[1].', ' .$row[2]. ' '.$row[3].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Gender: </b>'.$row[11].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Birthday: </b>'.$row[5].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Age: </b>'.$row[6].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Name of Main Household: </b>'.$childID.'<br><br>';
          echo '<div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white text-center rounded"><h6>Childs Health Information</label></h6></div><br>';
          echo '<b>Height: </b>'.$row[8].' cm <br>';
          echo '<b>Weight: </b>'.$childID.' kg <br>';
          echo '<b>BMI: </b>'.$row[9].'<br>';
           echo '<b>Date Weighed: </b>'.$row[13].'<br>';
          echo '<b>Health History: </b>'.$row[12].'<br>';
  echo '<b>Health Status: </b>'.$row[10].'<br>';

      }}}
?>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

for now, it will only echo the id that is last in the table and only that id.

Comment: Can you please clearly formulate a specific question?

Comment: I don't see your modal trigger in table code.

Comment: I have this clickable table where it only shows several columns of my database, I want to show the remaining columns in my pop up modal. How can I show the rest of the columns, I was thinking of passing the primary key of every row in the table so that clicking every row can show a different modal. @KIKOSoftware